# Determining the cause of AccessViolationException DragDrop.DoDragDrop

Tags: c#, debugging, access-violation

I have a WPF application that is crashing on some computers with an AccessViolationException when a drag operation is started.

The difficulty is it is only occurring on builds from our build server, and never crashes when I build locally in Visual Studio 2010. So I cannot step through the code.

I have the following information:

- We're using .net 4.0
- Only crashes when the application is run as a 64bit process, 32bit is fine.
- Only crashes for builds from the build server.
- Doesn't crash on every computer, just on a small subset of laptops we have here. Which   incidentally are all the same model
  and hardware configuration. All have
  Windows 7, and some have sp1, some
  don't.

What is the next step I should take to diagnose this issue?

Here's the stack trace from the crash, it seems to be occurring in unmanaged code:

```
at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DoDragDrop(IDataObject dataObject, IOleDropSource dropSource, Int32 allowedEffects, Int32[] finalEffect)
at System.Windows.OleServicesContext.OleDoDragDrop(IDataObject dataObject, IOleDropSource dropSource, Int32 allowedEffects, Int32[] finalEffect)
at System.Windows.DragDrop.OleDoDragDrop(DependencyObject dragSource, DataObject dataObject, DragDropEffects allowedEffects)
at Acquire.Common.UI.Behaviours.DragDropBehaviour.StartDrag(RoutedEventArgs e)
at Acquire.Common.UI.Behaviours.DragDropBehaviour.AttachedElementMouseMove(Object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseTrustedEvent(RoutedEventArgs args)
at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessStagingArea()
at System.Windows.Input.InputProviderSite.ReportInput(InputReport inputReport)
at System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.ReportInput(IntPtr hwnd, InputMode mode, Int32 timestamp, RawMouseActions actions, Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 wheel)
at System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.FilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, WindowMessage msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.InputFilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WrappedInvoke(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.InvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
at System.Windows.Application.Run()
at Acquire.Mica.Application.App.Main()
```

**Update:**
Through trial and error I was able to determine the exact line of code that was causing this crash, and it appears to be perfectly valid. As an experiment I disabled code optimization for the method containing the offending line of code, and the application no longer crashes.

Comment: Did you try the difference between Debug and Release builds from your local system? Perhaps some #if DEBUG statements are causing the different behaviour?

Comment: Which version of the Framework are you using?

Comment: Ow, something comes to mind. Is your event handler serializing anything by chance? This could cause problems when generating the serializer assemblies when not included in the build output. Or does it access any files or whatever that may cause this when not enough rights are granted? Perhaps Registry access for the wow6432 node?

Comment: @Sigh can you show your code where you call the DoDragDrop?

Comment: You mention an update, what exactly did you find?  Can we see the code that was optimized away?

Comment: Can you try building your project using Any CPU solution platform?

Comment: Can you decompile the offending assemblies and find out what is going on and that one line?  You can always get into the IL to find out why something is breaking. I've had situations a few times where everything worked locally but builds from our buildserver were failing and when I decompiled the built assemblies the problem revealed itself.

Comment: Mind sharing the line of code you're getting the crash on?

Comment: I was looking for this issue for a while, great question .

Answer (score 1):

AV exception are the worst, you should be aware that the problem may originate from completely different part in the system.

What normally happens is that you accidently access a memory location that you don't have access to, the program continues to execute as usual, however later on another method tries to access that memory location and causes an error by reading incorrect data place there by mistake.

To debug I suggest that you take advantage of [gflags](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdav_101/archive/2010/06/22/detecting-heap-corruption-using-gflags-and-dumps.aspx), a tool offered by Microsoft to detect deap corruptions. I used it several times and it saved me hours if not days of debugging effort.

Answer (score 0):

Just a hunch, but since you indicated you are optimizing code, and using a mixed 32/64 bit environment:

1. Verify the build server a x64 bit environment.
2. Verify the clients have the proper version .Net environment.
3. Verify the clients that are running the app are running the right version, ie. 64 bit is only being run by win7 x64 systems and vice versa.
4. Make sure you clear out the servers temp directories, previous builds in temp directories can cause odd issues such as this.

Also note, the Microsoft developers are idiotic in they way they segregated the two environments, and registry keys / program files etc. are not stored where the program indicates. This was a major stumbling block I had to get past with some apps we created at my company.

Also I belive clipboard & drag+drop calls are STA(Single threaded apratments) calls. The crash could be from a conflict between STA to MTA. Do you have the Main() function decorated with the  [STAThread] ?

I personally found this article on 64 bit migration useful: http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/misc/samples/basicprogramming/article.php/c16093/Seven-Steps-of-Migrating-a-Program-to-a-64bit-System.htm

Answer (score 0):

First of all check if all updates are installed on the machines.

Later you could use debugdiag to create a crashdump and check the firstchance and secondchance exceptions to get more info on the matter.

Greetings,

Ian

Answer (score 0):

1st thing I would do is to update the video card driver of those laptops.

at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods..

This usually means that MS .NET engineer trying to tell you:
"Hey, we didn't write this and it crashed."